# Query in Java- Initialization error

Tags: java

```
public class Switch {
    public static void main(String args[]){
        int month=4; 
        String season="";   // QUESTION: giving ERROR if not initializing here, y ?
        switch(month){
            case 12:
            case 1:
            case 2:
                season="Winter";
                break;
            case 3:
            case 4:
            case 5:
                season="Spring";
                break;
            case 6:
            case 7:
            case 8:
                season="Summer";
                break;
            case 9:
            case 10:
            case 11:
                season="Autumn";
                break;
            default:
              System.out.println("Bogus Month");

        }
        System.out.println("April is in the "+season+".");
       }
}
```

I created this example code using If else and there it was showing no initialization error for variable season but here it's showing initialization error for it. Where's wrong?

This is the same code using If else but here season wasn't initialized and yet gave no error.

```
public class IfElse {
    public static void main(String args[]){
        int month=4; 
        String season;

        if(month==12 || month==1 ||  month==2)
            season="Winter";
        else if(month==3 || month==4 || month==5)
            season="Spring";
        else if(month==6 || month==7 || month==8)
            season="Summers";
        else if(month==9 || month==10 || month==11)
            season="Autumn";
        else 
            season="Bogus Month";
        System.out.println("April is in the "+season+".");
    }
}
```

Comment: Instead of saying that you created the same code, you should just post that "same code" instead in the question.

Comment: Please tell the difference

Answer (score 2):

The difference is that in `switch`, the `default case` doesn't set anything for `season`. Try to set some value in `default` and don't initialize the variable. It will not give you an error.

Something like:

```
default:
   season = "default";
   System.out.println("Bogus Month");
```

This is because the compiler knows that before printing `season` value it will have some value set after executing the `switch` for sure since the `default` sets a value to `season`. Like in your `if-else` it is sure that `season` will have a value after it executes.

Comment: Thanks a lot for the answer, please clarify on this and tell me if I'm thinking kinda right or wrong. I was thinking that in If-Else it didnt give an error because season variable was initialized in the same block.                                        And in Switch season variable was just declared and not initialized in the outer block and that's why it was giving error in printing it ( even though season variable was initialized inside switch but as it was inside inner block it wasn't valid for outer block) ? I know I might sound dumb but I'm just trying to figure out from what I've learnt

Comment: As I said, it was not because of the scope of the variable, but because it was not initialized before it was use. The compiler makes sure that you initialize a local variable before you use it. Since your `if-else` block sets a value in any case it didn't give the error whereas in switch there was one case(default) where the value was not being set. It has nothing to do with same or outer block. @FalconZex

Answer (score 1):

> Local variables do not get default values, their initial values are undefined.
>   All member variable have to load into heap so they have to initialized with default values when an instance of class is created. In case of local variables, they don't get loaded into heap they are stored in stack until they are being used before java 7, so we need to explicitly initialize them.

In your second example when you use `if-else` statement the local variable `season` doesn't need to be initialize because you have in the end of statement `if-ifelse-else` below block:

```
             else 
            season="Bogus Month";
```

But if you remove this `else` statment you need to initialize it.
This means that the variable `season` will receive a value in each case, while with `switch-case` statement  not sure to receive a value unless you put the default value in the end of the `switch-case` statement  like this:

```
        default:
          System.out.println("Bogus Month");
           season="some value";
            break;
```

Comment: Please tell the difference

Comment: @FalconZex the difference between which?

Comment: Sorry, as I updated the question. I wanna know that the initialization error in switch is because season is initialized in the inner block and it is not valid for outer block where season is just declared and therefore it gives initialization error. Am I thinking right or wrong ?

Answer (score 0):

The error is, you need to initialize or set values for the variable "season" in all case. If you are not assigning value to "season" in any of the case, say in `case 6`, nothing to print (the variable not initialized/not assigned any value). The same error will occur when you remove statement in "IfElse" ie remove statement `season = "Autumn";`.